# How to set a map's extent to the envelope in miles

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I want to set extent of the map into envelope which sizes are defined by user in miles(kilometers, whatever human readable unit). How to make it? I wrote the following code:

```
static void ZoomToPoint(IActiveView focusMap, ExportJson2Feature.Geometry geom)
{
    IPoint point = new PointClass();
    point.PutCoords(geom.X, geom.Y);

    IEnvelope newExtentEnvelope = point.Envelope;
    newExtentEnvelope.Expand(1, 1, false);
    ((IGeometry)newExtentEnvelope).Project( ((IMap)focusMap).SpatialReference );
    focusMap.Extent = newExtentEnvelope;
}
```

How to make it know that sizeX/sizeY are in miles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geometry's coordinates are always specified in its spatial reference's units. Unit conversions are best done by using the [UnitConverter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0042/0042000002rq000000.htm) class.

If that's any help, you can determine the currently used map units by [IMap.MapUnits](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/001200000mm0000000.htm).

If your point coordinates are in lat/lon (such as the WGS84 spatial reference), you probably want to decide on a projected coordinate system first and use that when working with distances.

Answer (score 1):

If your extent will be covering a large range of latitudes or areas near the poles, you may benefit from calculating the extent using a geodesic distance from the centroid.

You can use [IConstructGeodetic.ConstructGeodesicCircle](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ConstructGeodesicCircle_Method/002m000000v0000000/) to create a polygon. Then you can invoke [IGeometry.Envelope](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Envelope_Property/002m00000209000000/) to get an envelope.